# How to write information to .csv file via streamwriter

Tags: windows, powershell, streamwriter

I am trying to write a lot of information to a .csv file using a powershell script. I'm running this script on 1500 computers from the "Run Script" function within SCCM Configuration Manager. The script runs on all the machines but not all machines have information written about them in the file. Out of 1352 machines, only 375 of those where written to the file. I suspect the program is either running too fast to open and close the file before the next machines runs the script and can't write to the file because it is still open. Any ideas how I can resolve this? I've seen posts about using StreamWriter but not sure that would resolve my problem.

I've tried breaking up the computers into smaller groups, like 8 at a time but only 5 of the 8 have information written to the file. The code is below and it works.

```
#Overrides GPO execution policy
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass


#Gets and writes computer name to .csv file
$env:COMPUTERNAME = HostName

#Checks the path to see if a particular file is present
$DeplPath = "AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties"


#Checks each user profile on machine for the deployment.properties file and writes to .csv "True" if present and "False" if it isn't
$javausers = foreach ($User in Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory){
    $folder = Join-Path $User.FullName $DeplPath
    if (Test-Path $folder) {
        $TestResult = "True  - deployment.properties"
    } Else {
        $TestResult = "False - Path not found"
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Computer Name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME 
        "Java User True/False"       = $TestResult
        "Users"         = $user.Name
        #"Last Write Time" = $file.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)

    }
}

#This is used for on-screen display only
#$javausers

#Tests path accessibility and writes an error file to the local machine if the path can't be found
try
{
$javausers | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "\\anyserver\Java_User_Reports\testjava.csv" -Append

}
catch
{
$_| Out-File "c:\Temp\java_error.txt"

}
```

I would like to have the information the script is searching for regarding each user to be written to the file for each of the 1500 machines.

Comment: This may be dumb, but I'd probably have each system write its own file. Then either read all 1500 files or merge the data later. You probably have more options if you don't use `Export-Csv`, but you lose other benefits by not using that.

Comment: @AdminOfThings  That has been a consideration. I was hoping to get some other option.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're writing to the file. You've got to open it for writing, and that means locking the file for writing which creates a race condition. Both Export-Csv and StreamWriter are going to have to do this, and file shares are notorious for retaining locks for longer than the remote application needs them. You'll still have the underlying race condition. If this is a Windows logon script, then you've also got to worry about scripts running before the network is available, which can also cause this type of issue.

Comment: (Csv) files are simply not suitable for writing from different account simultaneously, you will need a database that supports [record locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking) for that. Saying that you might use Active Directory for this (if already installed) which is in fact a database by itself, and use one or more (unused or special) user attribute for your information. Anyhow, I agree with @Bacon Bits , your next barrier will be [the Windows Fast Logon Optimization feature](https://support.microsoft.com/help/305293/description-of-the-windows-fast-logon-optimization-feature)

Comment: Thanks for the input for everyone. I just decided to add a timestamp at the end so it creates a new file every time for each machine and then just merge the data into one file as @AdminOfThings suggested. That works for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Manning Please write up an Answer, posting your solution. Then you can accept your own Answer by clicking the green Check icon. This marks the Questions as being resolved.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for the assist. Answer posted and accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a more simple solution by just adding a Get-Date option in the name of the file so that if also pulls the milliseconds, ensuring that a new file is created each time and the prior one would not be overwritten. This created 1365 files within minutes. I changed the output line to below:

```
$dateTime | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "\\anyserver\Java_User_Reports\$env:COMPUTERNAME-javausers-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmssff").csv" -Append
```

I then copied the files to a local folder on my machine, opened a command prompt, entered the command  to change the directory path where the files were sitting. I then typed the command  to view the files in the folder and ensure all the files I wanted were there. Finally, I typed copy *.csv newfilenamehere.csv so that all the information would be placed in one file. The results were exactly what I needed and resolved the problem of getting information from multiple computers without the script keeping a file open and not allowing other information to be written to it.

[image: .csv file results]